# How to check for duplication under some conditions in a data frame?

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have a data frame with given structure

```
 'data.frame':  3005 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ trial_id   : int  2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 2184 ...
 $ ctri_number: Factor w/ 278 levels "CTRI/2016/06/006993  ",..: 134 134 134 134 134 134 134 134 134 134 ...
 $ noofsites  : int  13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 ...
 $ Sites_Names: chr  "Acharya Tulsi Regional Cancer Treatment And Research Institute" "City Cancer Centre" "Curie Manavata Cancer Centre" "Government Stanley Medical College and Hospital" ...
 $ noofcom    : int  13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 ...
 $ ECs_Names  : Factor w/ 2493 levels "\"Aakash Healthcare Institutional Ethics Committee Aakash Healthcare Super Specialty Hospital Hospital Plot, Ro"| __truncated__,..: 218 210 211 1007 834 859 2047 2058 2096 2212 ...
```

There are a total of 278 unique trial_ids.
Each trial has more than 1 noofsite and thus their respective Names, each site name is in a different row. So for every trial, the number of rows = noofsites.

**I want to check - For every single trial if there is any duplication of Sites_Names. I don't want to check duplication of sites name in a whole data frame, only for a specific trial.**
How can this be achieved ???

Thankyou in advance

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @RonakShah, the expected output is the df with only trials having duplicate Site Names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want to `group_by(trial_id)` before checking for duplicates, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- mtcars %>%
  as_tibble() %>% 
  add_count(disp, name = "duplicates?")
df1
# A tibble: 32 x 12
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb `duplicates?`
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>         <int>
# 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4             2
# 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4             2
# 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1             1
# 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1             1
# 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2             2
# 6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1             1
# 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4             2
# 8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2             1
# 9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2             1
#10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4             2

df2 <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(carb) %>% 
  add_count(disp, name = "duplicates?") %>% 
  ungroup()
df2
# A tibble: 32 x 12
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb `duplicates?`
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>         <int>
# 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4             2
# 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4             2
# 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1             1
# 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1             1
# 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2             1
# 6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1             1
# 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4             1
# 8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2             1
# 9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2             1
#10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4             2

identical(df1, df2)
# FALSE
```

Here, duplicates are noted in the last column of each tibble. If you `group_by(carb)` before checking for duplicates, you get fewer duplicates than if you search the entire dataframe for duplicates (df1 and df2 are not identical). I.e. the dataset is grouped by "carb" and each group is searched for duplicates separately. Does this solve your problem?